# Open link in default browser - WebView Android Studio

Tags: android, webview

I need your help!

I have a webview done in Android Studio, it is working perfectly, however, I need it when I click on some link, it will open in the default browser.

**My MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.example.levelmax.powertuberprojetoapp;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
    import android.webkit.WebView;
    import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
private WebView view; //membuat variabel view agar bisa akses method onKeyDown

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    view = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    view.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    view.setWebViewClient(new AppWebViewClient());
    view.loadUrl("http://google.com"); //try js alert
    view.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient()); // adding js alert support
}


private class AppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }


}



public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    //ketika disentuh tombol back
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && view.canGoBack()) {
        view.goBack(); //method goback() dieksekusi untuk kembali pada halaman sebelumnya
        return true;
    }
    // Jika tidak ada history (Halaman yang sebelumnya dibuka)
    // maka akan keluar dari activity
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
}
```

Comment: You would get a better answer if you showed your code.

Comment: Really, I forgot to show my code, sorry! I've already edited my question.

Comment: add code formatting

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I do not know where to put this code that you gave me. Could you help me set up MainActivity.java?

OBs: I'm new to android Studio, I'm good even in PHP and JavaScript

Comment: I thank those who helped me. I found a solution from the colleague's reply just above.

Comment: Just use above code in `onCreate()` method.

`@Override`
`protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {`
    `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`
    `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`
     
      `Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://www.google.com"));`
      `startActivity(browserIntent);`

}`